# How do I edit an indefinite amount of mysql rows at a time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

I'm making a quotes system that will essentially allow somebody to accept a quote, all quotes are stored in a database.

When someone accepts quote #1, I want quote #2, #3, #4, and #5 (indefinite amount, could be more or less) to be automatically updated in the database. My problem is that there there is no set number of quotes, so I need to some how search for the unique ID of that commission and change them all; this is where I get lost.

Comment: Are quotes 2,3,4,5.. already in the database, what exactly did you want to update about them

Comment: Why do you need the unique ID's ? How is your database structured, since I would expect a simple query like: `UPDATE dbo.mytable SET ( accepted = 1 ) WHERE inputDate > dateOfQuote#1 AND accepted = 0`. ?

Comment: It would help to see your current SQL query and to know what you want to update about them... but can't you just include `WHERE id != accepted_id` (pseudo-code) to your update query?

Comment: @Shilly I need a unique ID as there are multiple different commissions logged in one table, henceforth each have a unique ID.

Comment: I'm very new to mysql, started using it a matter of days ago.

Essentially, a client can run a commission. The freelancer will reply with a quote, that gets logged into the database with a unique id for that single commission. One freelancer might log a quote, or 10 might, we don't know. Therefore, if quote number 1 is accepted, 2 through 10 need to be denied (Simply changing a columns contents from Pending to denied)

Comment: @TyTheOwl A frreelancer replying with a quote should always mention which commission they are quoting for. So inserting a quote into the DB should update the respective commission row with their own uniqueID. Once a quote gets chosen, you update the commission to be settled and get the uniqueID's of the other quotes to reject.

Comment: @Shilly that doesn't make all that much sense to me?

Answer (score 0):

Small example of a basic workflow.

1) A client runs a commission. That commission gets inserted into the database as commission X. You should provide a field in that commission row to add id references for quotes.

`INSERT INTO COMMISSIONS ( date, request, quotes ) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES ( 2019-xx-xx, 'make a logo', '[]' );`
This gives you the commission id X.

2) The client then sends out requests for quotes to freelancers mentioning X as the commission they should respond to. A freelancer replies with a quote for commission X.

3) You insert the new quote into the database. The INSERT gives you the unique id Y. You then search for commission X in the database and add Y to its quotes field.

`INSERT INTO QUOTES ( date, quote, state ) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES ( 2019-xx-xx, 'someBase64Image', 'pending' );` this gives you the quote id Y

`UPDATE COMMISSIONS SET quote = quote + 'Y' WHERE id = X;`

X is a given, since the freelancer responded to a certain commission request.
The quotes field needs some parsing rules depending on its data type.

4) The client chooses between the quotes and tell you which one they have chosen.

5) You search the database for the commission that contains the id Y in its quotes field. You now have the IDs of all the quotes for that commission from the commissions quotes field and can search+reject those ID's that aren't Y.

`UPDATE QUOTES SET state = 'accepted' WHERE id = Y;`

`SELECT * FROM COMMISSIONS WHERE [quotes] LIKE '%Y%';`
Extract all the quote IDs from the commission.
Loop over all those IDs.

`UPDATE QUOTES SET state = 'rejected' WHERE id = id_from_quotes_field_commission_X`

x) You can completely reverse this logic by having the quotes have a commission_id field so you can search for `WHERE commission_id = X` instead.

Update:

Since MySQL does not seem to have an OUTPUT equivalent, you can add a select query after the insert using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html